# How do I extract the location of a local file in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-file

I am trying to build a program and I need to allow the user to browse for a specific file in their phone and select a file. I am currently trying to extract the location of the selected file by the user in their phone but I have no idea how I can do that.
Can anyone suggest how I can do this, especially what tool I can use in my layout file and how I can extract the location in my main class?

Answer (score 0):

First we have to start intent on click of button
i.e.

```
private void openFileManager(int  CODE) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, CODE);
}
```

and we can get path in onActivityResult using

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    String FilePath = data.getDataString();

    //Whatever you want to do .....You can do here

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```